# Mysql: how to select rows where the combination of 2 of the column values are unique given a certain other column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like table `(id,C1,C2,R,..)`,and in this table,`C1-C2` pair is related to one or more `R`,for example `(id1,a,b,r1,...)`,`(id2,a,b,r2,...)`
I want to find out all `C1-C2` pairs that is only related to a certain `R` (e.g.for `r1`,then `a-b` pair will not be included,since it's also related to `r2`), how should I write the query?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `group by` and `having`.  I you want all pairs that are only related to one `r`:

```
select c1, c2, max(r) as r
from t
group by c1, c2
having min(r) = max(r);
```

If you have a particular `r` in mind:

```
select c1, c2
from t
group by c1, c2
having min(r) = max(r) and min(r) = 'r1'
```

Comment: Another question, if I want to see the information of other columns except the C1,C2  after the query, e.g.id, then dose GROUP BY still work?

Comment: @LiliZhu . . . No.  If that is your problem, you should ask another question, with appropriate sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You could group by C1 and C2 and count the number of "r"s that are equal to the value you want (and make sure it's not 0) and the number of "r"s that aren't (and make sure it is 0):

```
SELECT   c1, c2
FROM     mytbale
GROUP BY c1, c2
HAVING   COUNT(CASE r WHEN 'r1' THEN e END) > 0 AND
         COUNT(CASE r WHEN 'r1' THEN NULL ELSE 1 END) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks, the idea of  GROUP BY C1,C2 has solved my problem.